# Compare two columns and get the values from another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table with multiple columns, I need to add value for every transaction_id, how can i compare column C with column J and enter values from K into D column?

Table looks like this:

| C | D | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| transaction_id | amount | transaction_id | amount |
| 1 |  | 5 | 1000 |
| 2 |  | 1 | 1000 |
| 5 |  | 118 | 200 |
| 118 |  | 117 | 500 |

I need to match the exact transaction_id and move from the right to left amount value if transaction id is the same, how can I do that?

Comment: search for INDEX-MATCH-formula.

Comment: Thanks @Ike your solution works too =INDEX(K:K;MATCH(C2;J:J))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use VLOOKUP:

[image]

Formula in D is:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,$J$2:$K$5,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: It worked good thanks for the help, also I found INDEX MATCH solution sugested by ike